# Android busybox sed: bad option in substitution expression

Tags: android, regex, sed, busybox

I need to replace this lines

```
`<permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
        <group gid="sdcard_r" />
        <group gid="sdcard_rw" />
</permission>`
```

with this

```
`<permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
        <group gid="sdcard_r" />
        <group gid="sdcard_rw" />
        <group gid="media_rw" />
 </permission>`
```

with other words, I need to add  `group gid="media_rw"` in permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE if it's not included, in file `/system/etc/permissions/platform.xml` But I get error : bad option in substitution expression. I am using BusyBox v1.22.1 with all applets

My code:

http://pastebin.com/VTURRpDu .I posted code on pastebin because here my code is not showing correctly. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need pretty formatting, you'll have to inject newlines and tabs (which pain me in sed); an untidy but otherwise formed equivalent below:

I think you only need to match the insertion point (the penultimate or last line) thus:

```
cat infile | sed -e "s/<\/permission>/<group gid=\"media_rw\"\/><\/permission>/"
```

gives

```
<permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    <group gid="sdcard_r" />
    <group gid="sdcard_rw" />
<group gid="media_rw"/></permission>
```

Since I've always struggled with tabs and newlines in sed, awk'll do it nicely if you have it and you insist on pretty output.

```
cat infile | awk '/\/permission/ { print "\t<group gid=\"media_rw\"\/>";}
/./ {print $0;}
'
```

gives the same with a tab and a newline:

```
<permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    <group gid="sdcard_r" />
    <group gid="sdcard_rw" />
    <group gid="media_rw"/>
</permission>
```

**Edit: For in-file and against the group WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE tag**

I'll presume that the ordering of the key-value set within this block is not important. This will instead use the opening *permission* tag to perform the insertion, and now using *-i* on sed to edit the original file. Also switching to pipe separators (avoiding \/\/\/). Finally, using & to put matched text rather than type it out -- assuming your busybox build of sed can do this.

```
sed -e "s|<permission name=\"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE\" >$|&<group gid=\"media_rw\"/>|" -i infile
```

The tag you're matching only needs to be unique enough. Added EOL-marker ($) to the match part to replace this only once. The match will not work a second time because the line will have changed.

Comment: it works perfectly! thank you very much. but i have a little problem: group media_rw is adding every time I run the script. in ideal conditions, i need check if this group is added. if is included, I don't need to add this line again

Comment: Edit: Added $ to match text that will prevent re-application. I didn't know if you were after a 'start' in the direction of this working or of a complete solution.